# How to call custom search REST API MarkLogic Data hub 5

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I want to have a custom endpoint for search in which I can pass custom json object in body of POST Request
search-custom.sjs from which I want to call a xquery module.

/data-hub/src/main/ml-modules/services/search-custom.sjs has

function post(context, params, input) {
let request = JSON.parse(input)
return
xdmp.invoke("/lib/search-lib.xqy",request,[]);
}

exports.POST = post

But I am unable to invoke this xquery file.
Also If I call the endpoint from postman
http://localhost:8011/v1/resources/search-custom
body of POST Request
{
"searchField": "Title",
"searchTerm": "xzy",
"exclusionTerms":"Potential"
}

I am getting the no content (204)

/lib/search-lib.xqy has this code
let $_:= xdmp:log("Inside xquery search custom file")
return "this is xquery"

Even the logs are not getting logged in 8011_ErrorLog.txt

So, I am not sure if I am missing anything.

Moreover, how to get the body json params into xquery module to use those in xquery.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I would recommend making sure you also use the [marklogic] tag.  There are a number of people who keep an eye on that tag, but fewer who look at the specific version tags.

Comment: Sure, will do that going forward. But any idea how can we achieve this